# What is the point of Snapshot Dependencies without related Artifact Dependencies?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

What is the point of Snapshot Dependencies without related Artifact Dependencies?

I noticed that some TC Projects have Snapshot Dependencies without any Artifact dependencies.

What purpose does this serve?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can omit teamcity "artifacts" completely and use external system for storing artifacts.

In projects I work on we use [JFrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/). We chain builds using "Snapshot dependencies" to make sure that latest code is built and outputs are available, but we don't use "artifact dependencies" at all. All packages are downloaded using nuget.